# Find out the device for my cd drive in my unix VM

Tags: virtual-machine, opensuse

I have a suse linux 12 in a VM. I have connected a dvd to that machine (from VM Ware). But not able to see any difference under */media/* or */dev/* .My understanding is once i insert a media that should be visible under */media/*. How can i browse through the cd contents from terminal?

Comment: Sorry but this is a really trivial Linux handling question. As such, it likely belongs to another StackExchange site (U&L and SuperUser spring to mind)

Answer (score 1):

You've probably got a /dev/cdrom so just mount it via;

```
mkdir /whateveryouwant
mount /dev/cdrom /whateveryouwant
```

Try that.